# Javascript regex form validation -edge cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

The following regular expression accounts for almost all the cases I need to match.  Examples below.

```
/\bP(ost|ostal)?([ \.]*O(ffice)?)?([ \.]*Box)?\b/ig
```

For clarification -the string is lifted in full from an address field and being validated by jQuery Validator.  My workplace is unable to ship to a PO Box -hence the requirement.

Matched correctly

```
po box
p.o. box
post office box
PO. BOX
Post Box
Postal Box
```

Not matched correctly

```
19 boxton drive
3 box hill road
22 pop box street
121 pony box
15 posting street
```

These are valid addresses which incorrectly match

```
92 postal drive
17 post street
```

This is an invalid address which does not match

```
box 199
```

Comment: Is the regex only supposed to match variations on PO box addresses, and *not* match other addresses that have the terms "box" or "post" in the street or building names? And what form is the input in? E.g., a string containing only an address, or are you trying to extract an address from the middle of a longer string?

Comment: Perhaps a negative look-ahead might work? [Regexr example](http://regexr.com/3h35v).

Comment: @nnnnnn  The regex is supposed to match variations on PO box addresses and _italic_ not _italic_ match other addresses that contain the terms 'box', 'post', or 'postal'.  The input is in the form of a string input to an address field, and the verification is being done with jQuery Validator.

Comment: If you are validating a string that is supposed to contain only an address then you can start your regex with `^P` to match a "P" at the start of the string. Note that some countries have a concept of "Locked Bag 123" that you probably want to treat like a PO box. (Also, off-topic, but my own mailing address is a PO box and I find it really annoying when companies won't ship to it, in which case I normally take my business elsewhere.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Our products are very large.

Comment: Now I'm curious what your products are. My post office will accept delivery of items much larger than my actual box, they just leave a card in my PO box and then I have to go inside during business hours to collect the package. Obviously they have to draw the line somewhere, but if a single person can carry the box it's probably not too big...

Comment: @nnnnnn Vinyl printed aluminium signs -the kind you might see on the side of a building.  And yes -this is feature has been requested because users are ...well ...users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this one a shot:

```
/\bP(?:\.|o|ost(?:al)?)? ?(?:O(?:\.|ffice)?)? ?Box\b/ig
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/Eh6kMQ/1/ for an explanation and demo

Comment: Thank you.  I have modified the regex slightly and have one more case I am unable to account for: "applebox 14".  I know it's an edge case but I am trying to cater for as much as I can.  Please see: https://regex101.com/r/Eh6kMQ/3

Comment: Do you want it to match "applebox"? At the moment it isn't.

Comment: I would like it to match "box 199", and NOT match "15 applebox".  Again -thank you.

Comment: In the link you supplied you're matching "box 222" and not "14 Applebox" so it looks like you have what you need.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @Jon P.  Press enter after the "14 Applebox" string :)

Comment: It looks like you need a better definition of what is valid withot P(o|st|al). E.g what makes box 1222 valid, but box abc invalid. Can you guarantee that PO Boxes are purely numeric for your potential customer base? Furthermore, in your original question you explicitly state box 199 is invalid.

Comment: @pcgben You could replace `*` at the beginning of your regex to `+`, to exclude `14 Applebox`.